# Where is the syntax error

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I'm trying to run it on LocalHost.  I keep getting an unexpected token error.  Does anyone know why?

What I'm trying to do is make a simple API that takes inputs from the user and saves them onto a monogo database.

```js
var PodDoc = require('../models/pods.js');

module.exports = {
  save: save
}

function save(pod, callback){
  var podToSave = new PodDoc();
  podToSave.firstName = pod.firstName;
  podToSave.lastName = pod.lastName;
  podToSave.skills = pod.skills;
  podToSave.avatarUrl = pod.avatarUrl;
  podToSave.address = {
    address.number = pod.address.number; //This is where the Unexpected Token is
    address.lineOne = pod.address.lineOne;
    address.lineTwo = pod.address.lineTwo;
    address.postcode = pod.address.postcode;
  };
  podToSave.phoneNumbers = {
    podToSave.phoneNumbers.mobile = pod.phoneNumbers.mobile;
    podToSave.phoneNumbers.landline = pod.phoneNumbers.landline;
  }
  podToSave.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Cool!");
      callback();
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object properties are set this way:

```
var obj = {
  foo: "foo", //':' instead of '=' and ',' not ';'
  bar: "bar"    
};
```

If you want to set a property later on:

```
obj.test = "test";
obj["test"] = "test";

var test = "test";
obj[test] = test; //Using a variable value as property
```

But **not** like this:

```
var obj = {
  obj.foo: "foo" //syntax error
};
```

Here's your code fixed:

```
podToSave.address = {
    //number not address.number
    number: pod.address.number, //= and ; changed
    lineOne: pod.address.lineOne,
    lineTwo: pod.address.lineTwo,
    postcode: pod.address.postcode
  };
  podToSave.phoneNumbers = {
    mobile: pod.phoneNumbers.mobile,
    landline: pod.phoneNumbers.landline
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having another issue.  I'm running mongodb but in my other file  pods.js its telling me that mongodb isn't defined.  I've put the requirements in and I've looked over the code but can't see why it would output as undefined.